# Best way to check if lots of variables contain a string and if so change it?

Tags: php, function, variables, if-statement

I have lots of variables that I need to check to see if it is equal to "None". If a variable is equal to "None" I would like to change it to = "-";

What's the best practice way of doing this without having a separate IF function for each variable?

```
//Variables
$profileEthnicity = h($result["profile_ethnicity"]);
$profileHeight = h($result["profile_height"]);
$profileBuild = h($result["profile_build"]);
$profileEyeColor = h($result["profile_eye_color"]);
$profileHairColor = h($result["profile_hair_color"]);
$profileTattoos = h($result["profile_tattoos"]);
$profilePiercings = h($result["profile_piercings"]);

//Example
if($profileEthnicity == "None") { $profileEthnicity = "-"; }
```

Comment: What is the source of these variables? This type of filtering operation would be made easier if they were all in an array. They could be assembled into an array, but if `$result` came from a database lookup, that array could be used directly.

Comment: Are there other keys in the `$result` array you are not using here or not assigning to variables?  In practice, if I get values from an array I would prefer to continue using them as an array rather than store each into individual variables. I rarely find that necessary, and it tends to inflate code (separate `if` for each variable like you wanted to avoid)

Comment: one method is to change all your vars into an array with your descriptor as the key, ie. `$profile['Ethnicity']`. Then you can do a `foreach()` loop over the array, instead of doing a manually coded `if()`

Comment: we can use ternary operator  $profilePiercings = ($profileEthnicity == "None") ?  "-" : $profileEthnicity; Or use array_map      function isnoneExists($item){   return($item == "None") ?  "-" : $item; } 
    $resultArr = (array_map("isnoneExists",$result));

Comment: You already have an array, `$result` that you can loop through.

Comment: What does the `h()` function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values are in an array you can do this:

```
foreach($result AS $key => $val) {
    ('None' == $val) ? $result[$key] = '-' : $result[$key] = $val;
}
```